# Select placeholder missing after selecting in AntDesign

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a form that has selects a type of holiday. But the placeholder went missing after selecting. I created a reset button to see if the value of select is resetting.

How can I reset it to initial state with placeholder?

I created the scenario here
[Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-goldberg-4ej5f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replicated your https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-violet-3vpw7 sandbox here and just removed the valueProp** u passed to the getFieldDecorator.